# BoldDays for TDateTimePicker?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, datetimepicker, typography, monthcalendar

I'm using Delphi7 and I'd like to bold some days of a `TDateTimePicker` control.

I've read that, originally, it's a descendant of `TMonthCalendar`, thus it should be possible.

I've also found some example code, but it's in C#:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/03527023-694d-41ab-bffb-18c59fca1fda

Please note that I don't want to use any third party `DateTimePicker` controls, I'd like to stay with the standard one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are both right and wrong :-)

See:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/MFC/Q_23927552.html

You are right that you can't set BoldDays under XP.
But you are wrong because under Vista/Win7 you can!

Here is the modified code:

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
const
  DTM_GETMCSTYLE = (DTM_FIRST + 12);
  DTM_SETMCSTYLE = (DTM_FIRST + 11);
  MCS_NOTRAILINGDATES = $0040;
  MCS_SHORTDAYSOFWEEK = $0080;
  MCS_NOSELCHANGEONNAV = $0100;
var
  monthCalHandle: THandle;
  boldDates: array[0..2] of integer;
  style, prevstyle: LResult;
begin
  style := SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, 0, 0);
  style := style or MCS_DAYSTATE; //or MCS_NOSELCHANGEONNAV or MCS_WEEKNUMBERS;
  prevstyle := SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, 0, style);

  monthCalHandle := SendMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);

  boldDates[0]:=$5a5a5a;
  boldDates[1]:=$5a5a5a;
  boldDates[2]:=$5a5a5a;
  SendMessage(monthCalHandle, MCM_SETDAYSTATE, 3, integer(@boldDates));
end;
```

**Note: be sure to add a vista manifest to the file because otherwise it won't work!**

The constants are from an updated commctrl.h file, found here:
http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid6A6537D52B537D0920D7A760D2073F7B65ADE310.aspx?s=WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT

Thanks for the help, you lead me to the solution! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution cannot and does not work. As soon as you change the view, like selecting a different month etc., you lose bold information. The month calendar requests that information when it needs it. As stated in `MCM_SETDAYSTATE`'s  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/mcm-setdaystate): *An application can explicitly set day state information by sending this message, but the state will not persist when a different part of the calendar is scrolled into view*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want, because the MonthCalendar displayed in response of the dropDown button press in the DateTimePicker is a MonthCalendar that has no MCS_DAYSTATE style set. This is a Microsoft decision. It is not a VCL limitation, so there is nothing, to my knowledge, you can do to change it. The only thing would be not to use it and instantiate a real MonthCalendar of your own in response to the user press of the dropdown button; or use some of the custom components already available.

To prove it, here is a Pascal version of the same C# code you posted. It does not work and to my knowledge it never will. If you want to test it, hook it into the DropDown event of the DateTimePicker.

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
 var
   monthCalHandle: THandle;
   boldDates: array[0..2] of integer;

 begin
  { obtain the MonthCalendar handle using the DTM_GETMONTHCAL message
    note that the handle returned changes for every time the
    drop down calendar is displayed. }
  monthCalHandle := SendMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);

  { Send the MCM_SETDAYSTATE message. This message takes an array of
    3 MONTHDAYSTATEs. Every MONTHDAYSTATE is a bit set that represents a month.
    Each bit (0 through 30) represents the state of a day. Whan a bit is on,
    its corresponding day is emphasized in the MonthCalendar }
  boldDates[0]:=$5a5a5a;
  boldDates[1]:=$5a5a5a;
  boldDates[2]:=$5a5a5a;
  SendMessage(monthCalHandle, MCM_SETDAYSTATE, 3, integer(@boldDates));
 end;
```

Comment: +1 after playing with it for a while, I believe you are right.