# How do you programmatically mark a date in Delphi's TDateTimePicker's calendar?

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

When users click a DateTimePicker, set to drop down a calendar, I would like various dates (chosen via code I create) to highlighted in some way--colored background, bold font, colored font, it doesn't matter. I just want certain dates to be marked. ... How would I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. First, you have to initialize the control:

```
const
  DTM_GETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 12;
  DTM_SETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 11;
...
SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle,
  DTM_SETMCSTYLE,
  0,
  SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, 0, 0) or MCS_DAYSTATE);
```

(`uses CommCtrl`).

Then you simply have to respond to the `MCN_GETDAYSTATE` notification. Either you can create your own `TDateTimePicker` descendant, or you can use an 'interceptor class'.

```
type
  TDateTimePicker = class(ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker)    
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

  ...

procedure TDateTimePicker.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_NOTIFY:
      with PNMDayState(Message.LParam)^ do
        if nmhdr.code = MCN_GETDAYSTATE then
        begin
          // The first visible day is SystemTimeToDateTime(stStart);
          // cDayState is probably three, because most often three months are
          // visible at the same time. Of course, the second of these is the
          // 'currently displayed month'.
          // Each month is represented by a DWORD (32-bit unsigned integer)
          // bitfield, where 0 means not bold, and 1 means bold.
          // For instance, the following code will select all days:
          for i := 0 to cDayState - 1 do
            PMonthDayState(Cardinal(prgDayState) + i*sizeof(TMonthDayState))^ := $FFFFFFFF;
        end;
  end;
end;
```

Another example: Assume that the current display consists of three months, and that you only want to select days in the 'currently displayed month', that is, in the middle month. Assume that you want every third day to be selected, starting with a selected day.

Then you want to use the bitfields

```
Month  Bitfield
0      00000000000000000000000000000000
1      01001001001001001001001001001001
2      00000000000000000000000000000000
```

which are

```
Month  Bitfield
0      $00000000
1      $49249249
2      $00000000
```

in hexadecimal. So you do

```
for i := 0 to cDayState - 1 do
  if i = 1 then
    PMonthDayState(cardinal(prgDayState) + i*sizeof(TMonthDayState))^ := $49249249
  else
    PMonthDayState(cardinal(prgDayState) + i*sizeof(TMonthDayState))^ := $00000000;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Notice that this will only work on Windows Vista and later, e.g. since  [`DTM_GETMCSTYLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761763(VS.85).aspx) was introduced in Vista.

Comment: I suppose that the operating system allocates and frees the `prgDayState` buffer... The documentation is not entirely clear on this point.

Comment: Is it true thta the VCL's OnGetMonthInfo / OnGetMonthBoldInfo too work only on Vista and later (ie use the same DTM_GETMCSTYLE / DTM_SETMCSTYLE messages)? It isn't mentioned in the help...

Comment: @ain, TMonthCalendar intercepts MCN_GETDAYSTATE and works for at least XP and up, but this interface was not implemented in the windows DateTimePicker. The DTM_GETMCSTYLE/DTM_SETMCSTYLE is not used in the current Delphi XE implementation.

Comment: Now why did I know the answer was by Andreas even before I got to the end?

Comment: It is very considerate that the `WM_NOTIFY` message in the case of a `MCN_GETDAYSTATE` notification is sent to the Date and Time Picker Control and not to the parent of the Month Calendar Control like it always [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-notify). The actual parent of the Month Calendar is one of a "DropDown" class, the DropDown or the MonthCalendar has no window relation with the Date and Time Picker - no parentship, no ownership. I wonder what kind of trickery does the window manager play. Anyway, thanks for the code.

Answer (score 4):

[OnGetMonthInfo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.OnGetMonthInfo) event looks at [BoldDays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.BoldDays) array to mark days in a month.

Extracted from the help :

> Use BoldDays to encode the days of the current month that should appear in bold. 
>       The value returned by BoldDays can be assigned to the MonthBoldInfo parameter of an OnGetMonthInfo event handler. 
>   Days is an array of unsigned integers corresponding to the days that should be bold.

Look it up in the help.

Edit :

DateTimePicker.BoldDays is accessible.

OnGetMonthInfo is deprecated in Delphi XE, use OnGetMonthBoldInfo instead.
Still havent figured out best way to reintroduce the event yet.

Edit 2 :
I did have a go with reintroducing the event, but it seems that the windows message is not tied in TDateTimePicker. Too bad. 
I guess Andreas solution with going straight to the windows message api is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I really appreciate it ... Are you thinking of something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223237/bolddays-for-tdatetimepicker?

Comment: This answer applies to `TMonthCalendar`, and *not* to `TDateTimePicker`.

Comment: @Andreas, according to help, TCommonCalendar (where OnGetMonthInfo belongs) is an inherited member of TDateTimePicker.

Comment: The OnGetMonthInfo event is introduced in `TCommonCalendar`, anchestor for both TMonthCalendar and TDateTimePicker - perhaps it is still possible to use it with TDateTimePicker? Althought the TDateTimePicker doesn't publish it...

Comment: After some investigation it appears the OnGetMonthInfo event and DTM_GETMCSTYLE styles just will not work for the TDateTimePicker control in Windows XP.